# Elif statement with 2 variables

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that returns a grade point average for a score and my syntax is apparently not right. Any suggestions?

```
average = sum(first_score, second_score, third_score, fourth_score, fifth_score)

if average >= 90 or <= 100:
    print('A')
elif average >=80 or <= 90:
    print('B')
elif average >= 70 or <= 79:
    print('C')
elif average >= 60 or <= 69:
    print('D')
else: 
    print('F')
```

Comment: Where does python say the syntax error is? The if/elif block shouldn't be indented and would certainly cause the problem. BTW, average is the sum divided by the number of items.

Comment: The error comes at the second elif line second argument

Comment: The second elif is invalid syntax, but so is the first 'if' and the other 'elif's. You can't be showing us the code you use! You need a variable between the 'or' and the '<=" - but see the answers for the correct logic.

Comment: Please do _not_ edit the question in such a way that it invalidates all the answers. You're free to augment the question to add extra information but changing its very nature makes the whole Q&A idea useless. If you change it so much that it's a different question, it should be _asked_ as a different question.

Comment: I wasn't able to reply  because of points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sum) sums a single iterable.  So, you need to give it one:

```
# Note the extra parenthesis
average = sum((first_score, second_score, third_score, fourth_score, fifth_score))
```

Second, you can't use `or` like that.  Instead, you should chain the comparisons like this:

```
if 90 <= average <= 100:
```

Third, you missed a colon after the `else`.

Finally, I want to say that your formula for the average is wrong.  The average of a group of numbers is calculated by the sum of the numbers divided by the number of numbers.

---

Here is a fixed version of the script:

```
scores = (first_score, second_score, third_score, fourth_score, fifth_score)
average = sum(scores)/len(scores)
if 89 < average < 101:
    print('A')
elif 79 < average < 90:
    print('B')
elif 69 < average < 80:
    print('C')
elif 59 < average < 70:
    print('D')
else:
    print('F')
```

Also, I slightly adjusted the numbers so that I could use `<` instead of `>=`.  I did this because the former requires less syntax.

Comment: I like that the attempted logic says you get an A if your average is either over 90 or under 100. Grading on a pretty generous curve!

Answer (score 5):

First of all, your conditions need to be `and`s, not `or`s

```
if 100 >= average >= 90:  # same as if 100 >= average and average >= 90
    print('A')
elif 89 >= average >=80:
    print('B')
elif 79 >= average >= 70:
    print('C')
elif 69 >= average >= 60:
    print('D')
else:
    print('F')
```

Comment: I think it's important to note the `:` after the `else`.  This was the `SyntaxError` before.

Comment: @SethMMorton - One of the `SyntaxError`s anyways.  His (the OP's) use of the comparison operators is also wrong.

Answer (score 4):

```
if 90<= average: return 'A'
elif 80 <= average: return 'b'
```

you dont need to check the upper bound ... since at the line we have already established it is less than 90

Comment: How about `average >= 90` which is the same as you wrote but perhaps a bit easier to read?

Comment: yeah I was going to do `x < y < z` ... but than realized the `<z` didnt matter

Answer (score 3):

First things first, that syntax is wrong. If you want to test it with boolean operations like `and` and `or`, you need to make the sub-expressions fully self contained:

```
if average >= 90 or average <= 100:
#                   ^^^^^^^
```

Secondly, you're using the *wrong* boolean operation. Think about the possible values you can test with:

```
       >=90(a)   <=100(b)    a or b
 89      F          T           T         < 90
 90      T          T           T           90
 95      T          T           T         > 90 and <100
100      T          T           T          100
101      T          F           T         >100
```

Every single one of those `or` statements would be true (if they executed - they won't, of course, since the first one will always fire). The correct boolean operation to use here is `and`:

```
if average >= 90 and average <= 100:
#                ^^^
```

Thirdly, your ranges actually overlap such as with the value `90` which would fall in both the `A` and `B` ranges. You should make one end exclusive and the other inclusive, such as with:

```
if average >= 90 and average < 100:
#                           ^
```

Which end is inclusive depends on your needs, I've made it the lower end to be easier on the students :-)

Lastly, since you're using `elif`, you don't have to check both ends of the range. The fact that you've already evaluated one end in a *previous* `if/elif` statement means that it's a given that you are correct at that end. In other words, looking at the below code, the value `95` will never trigger the second condition despite it being true, since it would have *already* triggered the first condition:

```
if average >= 90:      # 90 to infinity
    print('A')
elif average >= 80:    # 80 to 89.999...
    print('B')
elif average >= 70:    # 70 to 79.999...
    print('C')
elif average >= 60:    # 60 to 69.999...
    print('D')
else:
    print('F')         # -infinity to 59.999...
```

---

As an addendum, one other thing you *may* want to look at is that you appear to be just *summing* the scores to get an average (and with an incorrect syntax since `sum` wants an iterable list). If those scores are percentages, you'll probably need to divide the sum by five to scale it back to a percentage, lest you end up with a number between `0` and `500`, such as with a simple:

```
average = (first + second + third + fourth + fifth) / 5
```

or a more generalised:

```
scores = (first, second, third, fourth, fifth)
average = sum (scores) / len (scores)
```

You can safely ignore this addendum if your scores are marks out of twenty, or have some other mathematical relationship that would cause a simple sum to return a percentage.